# Opera works only with root rights

Tags: permissions, sudo, opera

Opera doesn't start unless I start it with `sudo opera`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/366919/edit) what version of Ubuntu and how you install opera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running it once as root (via `sudo`) the ownership of your opera profile are set to root. You should correct this. Change the owner of `.opera` and all subdirectories and files (with `-R` recursive option):

```
sudo chown -R group_name.user_name ~/.opera
```

and it should work.