# Opera-stable seems to lack premissions/privileges in 14.04

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, privileges, opera

So I installed the official version of Opera named "opera-stable" in the Ubuntu Software Center.

- When I run it from launcher, it launches twice and displays a message (Translated to English by myself, may not be perfect):

> Cannot read user configuration files. Some features may not be
>   available and any changes performed this session will not be saved. ([Print Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt470.png))

- When I run it from terminal, it throws these errors:

> [1226/165646:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(889)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
>   [1226/165646:ERROR:download_history_importer.cc(50)] Failed to read a tag or its data.
>   [1226/165646:ERROR:migration_assistant.cc(87)] Could not open file: wand.dat [1226/165646:ERROR:extensions_importer.cc(58)]
>   Reading widgets.dat failed

- **Running it with the "sudo" command works perfectly well**, and saves all user settings. Though from what I read so far, having to run a browser with sudo is not a good thing.

Now, I'm a newbie, but I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366919/ubuntu-opera-works-only-with-root-rigths) which recommends:

> sudo chown -R group_name.user_name ~/.opera

and indeed I seem to be the owner of all the folders and subfolders that opera uses (I can't remember the command I used to check that) but it still doesn't work.

I also tried loads of other things like updating, upgrading, apt-mark hold command, reinstalling opera (both using the software center and manually unpacking .deb file) and maybe something more. As I said, I'm a newbie, I only use Ubuntu for 2 days, I just want to get Opera up and running properly, but I spent those 2 days looking for an answer.

Any idea?

Edit:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq9rK.png)'s a screenshot of .opera's permissions. Sorry for the language. I should switch to English.

Comment: Right-click on `.opera` > Properties > Permissions and then edit your answer with the screenshot

Comment: Do you remember running this command - `sudo nautilus` ?

Comment: Ehm, could you tell me where do I find ".opera"?

And no, I've never seen the nautilus command

Comment: Goto` /home/<username>` and then press `Ctrl `+ `H`

Comment: Added screenshot. Should I change everything to "creating and deleting files"?

Answer (score 0):

First launch nautilus as root. To do that type the following:

```
gksu nautilus
```

Then right-click on `/home/<username>/.opera` and click on `Properties`, then to `Permissions`.

If you are unable to find `.opera` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show the folder.

Now, change

`Owner` to `<username>`

`Group` to `<username>`

And all else to:

[image: 1]

Also, check similarly for your `/home` & `/home/<username>` folders.

**EDIT**: Also, change the permissions of the following folders to the one as shown in your shared screenshot:

`/home/<username>/.cache/opera`

&

`/home/<username>/.config/opera`

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said but unfortunutely it didn't work. The error message still pops up when I run Opera, and the terminal still displays error messages before running Opera.

Comment: @swifterik - checking, will reply in a few minutes

Comment: @swifterik - edited!!

Comment: Both config and cache are alredy set like this. Maybe I should set them to access file as well?

Comment: opera inside config and cache?

Comment: yes .config/opera & .cache/opera

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, reinstalled Ubuntu and installed Opera from opera.com and it works OK. Hopefully it's rare for this problem to occur. I must've done something terribly wrong to cause that.